# How to get code from git in windows

Tags: android, git, window, android-source

Me working in Windows, so for Git I downloaded and installed msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.3.1 from [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list). And run as specified there. Then I tried to get Gallery application from [Android open source project](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git;a=summary), as specified there in my git console:

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git
```

it shows the following error `No such file or directory`

[image]

What did I miss here? I don't if know is this the correct way to get code from Android on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled the hostname in your screen capture.  I just tried it with the hostname you specified, and received the message:

```
$ git clone git://android.git.kernal.org/platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git
Cloning into Gallery...
android.git.kernal.org[0: 68.171.33.192]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
```

It's kernel.org, not kernal.org.

Comment: Thanks alot Simon. My carelessness :(. ya it was Kernel now it work fine

Comment: @Labeeb Btw: you can paste contents into the windows command-window by right-clicking into it.

Answer (score 1):

I also have [mysis git for windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) (version 1.7.3.1-preview20101002)... 
I pasted your command in and it worked!

```
$ git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git
Cloning into Gallery...
remote: Counting objects: 1056, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (402/402), done.
remote: Total 1056 (delta 457), reused 1041 (delta 450)
Receiving objects: 100% (1056/1056), 952.46 KiB | 292 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (457/457), done.

$ ls Gallery
Android.mk  AndroidManifest.xml  CleanSpec.mk  MODULE_LICENSE_APACHE2  NOTICE  res  src  tests
```

Is it possible there's a firewall blocking your connection? - http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/957-cant-clone-over-http-or-git

Comment: Me also downloaded from there, Which version you used  msysGit-fullinstall or msysGit-netinstall or PortableGit or Git-1.7.3.1 ?

Comment: Thanks PandaWood for your Quit Response. It was that spelling mistake which made all troubles :(